# What is wrong with the mod-rewrite regex?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite

tagged.php?flag=parameter&page=1

into

/parameter/?page=1

So I am using:

RewriteRule Hotties/?(.*)   tagged.php?flag=parameter&page=$1

However the result I am getting is:

/parameter/?page=

Which is the "1".  I am not sure what is missing.   Clearly the issue is with the (.*) and the "=" but I am not sure what is wrong.  I also tried (.*$) which did not fix it.

Comment: What is parameter? A word, digits, dashes? Please provide the specification as RewriteRules are best when exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you need to match against the URL path and the query string separately. If this is really your question,

> I am trying to rewrite
>
> tagged.php?flag=parameter&page=1
>
> into
>
> /parameter/?page=1

then you'd use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} flag=parameter&page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/tagged.php$ /parameter/?page=%1
```

but I suspect you actually want to go the other way around, in which case you'd use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/parameter/$ /tagged.php?flag=parameter&page=%1
```

Not sure where the "Hotties" thing comes into it.

Comment: That will not work. The appropriate syntax is $1. You're also not escaping the `?` in the query string. Your rule would also match `parameterpage=1`

Comment: Oh yeah, silly me, wrong regex engine. (I've been working with a bunch of different ones recently so I get them mixed up) I've edited.

Comment: Yea, I just forgot to escape the ? that fixed it.